# Accessing function from external popup window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a google extension, which I have created a popup window using:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.windows.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL("info.html"), 'type': 'popup'}, function(window) {
 });
});
```

It opens up a local HTML page (info.html) include another script for itself. in which I want to access some function from the background script. 
I have already tried:

```
var mypage = chrome.extension.getViews({"type":"popup"});
mypage.Somefunction();
```

Which the first line returns empty, and I think the problem is that the page is not in the chrome.extension scope.

Any hints would be appreciated.

**Update#1**

I have tried this as well. However,
if using the `extension.getBackgroundPage()` method, when I have a function in `background.js`:

```
function changedemo(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Well'
}
```

When I call it in the script using:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
  backgroundPage.changedemo();
});
```

I got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` even though it is handled by the listener.

Comment: Do you have an element with id `demo` in your `info.html` file? `document.getElementById("demo")` looks for this element and it returns `null` because it can't find it. - Anyway, why don't you set up a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/) demo, so we can debug your code?

Comment: @JohnSlegers I am sure I did. Here is the draft code:
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/f9xavwLg/)

Answer (score 0):

Scope of background page and popup page are different.
You can use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to access functions from the background script

The better way:

```
var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage(); 
background.Somefunction();
```

Comment: I thought only the content script is in isolate environment?

Comment: window obj for background and popup are different so cannot use its methods or variables directly

Comment: thanks for the advice, I have changed my prospective to this and it works!

Comment: @kohope8 background page has no direct access to any web-page's DOM.
If you want to access the web-page DOM, you have to:
Inject a content script into the web-page or pass a message to that content script, so it can manipulate the DOM element for you.